# Do we have this symbol in mathematics?

Tags: notation

[image]

It is the symbol I used to show left hand side of inequality isn't greater than right hand side.

More precisely I used this to show the below matrix is not diagonally dominant:

$$\begin{bmatrix}5&6&7\\
2&-4&2\\
3&2&-5\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

So at the first row I want to emphasize that $|5|$ is not greater than $|6|+|7|$  therefor instead of writing $|5|<|6|+|7|$ I used the symbol in the image above.

Is it ok to use this symbol in mathematics?

Comment: Isn't this just $<$?

Comment: I would rather say : it is just "<"

Comment: @Randall to show not equal we use $\neq$ so I wrote this to show it is not greater or equal.

Comment: For a partial ordering, I think it might make sense to speak of $a\not ≥ b$.  For a total ordering, as here, why not write $a<b$?

Comment: It is supported in Latex $\ngeq$ so it must be be correct.

Comment: I know it is the same as $<$ but in this specific problem I want to emphasize left side isn't greater so I used this notation.

Comment: @Tavish Because it is in Latex ?

Comment: @soheil  I think that makes it more confusing.

Comment: I think it's fine. When it comes to pedagogy, you're the artist.

Comment: @Peter Yes, it must be somewhat common to use.

Comment: https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: It is common enough that unicode has a code point `U+2271` ≱ for that.

Comment: We could also write $\frac{204}{102}$ for $2$, mathematically correct. But it would not make much sense to use this notation.

Comment: Closed as Opinion-based? Really? Then why we have notation tag on the site if notations are based on opinion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, it is OK. Putting a bar/cross on a pre-existing maths symbol just means the negation of it.

I'm not sure it is standardized, though.

**Edit**

As shown by @Dietrich Burde in his answer, these symbols are $\LaTeX$ [symbols](https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols), so that's clearly OK you can use them.

[image: LaTeX symbols with negations.]

Answer (score 3):

I would also say that we have both relations
$$
x \not\le y, \quad x\not \ge y.
$$
There are variants, of course, like
$$
x \lneq y,\quad x \gneq y 
$$
and
$$
x\nless y, x\ngtr  y
$$

Comment: Just to say:  I'd have no guess as to how to interpret $x\lneq y$.  To the extent that it means "$x$ is less than but not equal to $y$" then you could just write $x<y$, so I'd imagine that it meant something else...but what?  I would not guess that it meant $x>y$.

Comment: @lulu  The second option has its own LateX command, but it seems just to say that $x<y$ or $x>y$, I agree. Perhaps this is more evident for sets, where $A \subsetneq  B$ explicitly says that equality doesn't hold, because $A\subset B$ is ambiguous.

Comment: Ah, good point.  I agree, I wouldn't take $A\subset B$ to exclude $A=B$.